# How to open the phone camera using the "Choose File" button when called from responsive program (HTML5)

Tags: android, html, android-studio

I have a Responsive Program written in HTML5 and an app written in Android Studios. I'm told I have to have the Android program handle the opening of the camera when a user presses the  "Choose File" option on the program page to take a picture. We had our web-base program converted in the Responsive Program format so that it can be used from the phones and a small Android app so people can access it. If I go directly to my browser on my phone and select the "Choose File" option it works find, but I'm not sure how to write the code to get it to open up from the app I created when the same button is pressed. I'm new at Android Programming and could use some help to get this up and running. Here are copies of what my program looks like so far. Thanks in advance for any help anyone can give me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public WebView web1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    WebSettings webSettings = web1.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web1.loadUrl("https://wastefreemail.com");
    web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);


}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />





   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">


        </activity>
       <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
           <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>



    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int SLEEP_TIMER = 3;

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


     LogoLauncher logoLauncher = new LogoLauncher();
    logoLauncher.start();


}

private class LogoLauncher extends Thread{
  public void run(){
      try{
          sleep(1000 * SLEEP_TIMER);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){
          e.printStackTrace();

      }

      Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete solution, ripped from [this GitHub Project](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp), I suggest you to take a look at the mentioned repo to understand better how following script works.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    WebView web1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23
           && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
           || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        assert web1 != null;
        WebSettings webSettings = web1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            web1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            web1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else {
            web1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        web1.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        web1.loadUrl("https://wastefreemail.com");
        web1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 16+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 21+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

                //Checking for storage permission to write images for upload
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, perms, FCR);

                    //Checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, FCR);

                    //Checking for CAMERA permissions
                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, FCR);
                }
                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = null;
                takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(web1.canGoBack()){
                        web1.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Keep your Manifest as it is and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android-AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) to load a webpage in android app,it will handle file choose action automatically.

reedit:

In AdvancedWebView's init method,there is some code:

```
super.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   ...
}
```

In this WebChromeClient ,there is a method  `onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)`,change this method's logic by following code snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
                        &&fileChooserParams != null && fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()[0].startsWith("image")) {
        webview.selfDefineImageChoose(null,filePathCallback);//add selfDefineImageChoose method for AdvancedWebView
        //trigger photo shoot with your code
        });
        return true;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
//  return super.onShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
}
```

//add following method for your self defined AdvancedWebView.

```
public void selfDefineImageChoose(final ValueCallback<Uri> fileUploadCallbackFirst, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> fileUploadCallbackSecond){
        if (mFileUploadCallbackFirst != null) {
            mFileUploadCallbackFirst.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFileUploadCallbackFirst = fileUploadCallbackFirst;

        if (mFileUploadCallbackSecond != null) {
            mFileUploadCallbackSecond.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFileUploadCallbackSecond = fileUploadCallbackSecond;

}
```